# Wrapping tuples to be used as keys in a Dictionary

Tags: c#, hash-map, wrapper

I'm currently working on a project where I have to map some objects to several properties.

Basically I need a Dictionary with Tuples as keys and instances of MyClass as values.

As using tuples can quickly lead to an obscure (because of item1, item2... properties) and verbose code I decided to make a class to wrap the tuples.

```
class Key
{
    private Tuple<string, int, int, int> _impl;

    public Key(string unitID, int address, int comPort, int id)
    {
        _impl = new Tuple<string, int, int, int>(unitID, address, comPort, id);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return _impl.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return _impl.Equals(obj);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _impl.ToString();
    }
}
```

That way I should take advantage of the Tuple class and avoid its inconvenients.

So I can write:

```
Dictionary<Key, MyClass> mapping = new Dictionary<Key, MyClass>();
```

Instead of:

```
Dictionary<Tuple<string, int, int, int>, MyClass> mapping = new Dictionary<Tuple<string, int, int, int>, MyClass>();
```

And look up the dictionary like this:

```
Key key = new Key("abc", 1, 5, 5464);
MyClass myInstance = mapping[key];
```

Is this implementation correct ? Is there a more proper way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> ```
> public Key(string unitID, int address, int comPort, int id)
> ```

Clearly this class represents something much more specialized than an all-purpose "key". Name the type for what it stands for!

> ```
> private Tuple<string, int, int, int> _impl;
> ```

The private field should be `readonly`. But why don't you have this instead?

```
private readonly string _unitId;
private readonly int _address;
private readonly int _comPort;
private readonly int _id;
```

> ```
> public override int GetHashCode() 
> {
>     return _impl.GetHashCode(); 
> }
> ```

Ideally your `GetHashCode` implementation should rely on immutable fields. Your `_impl` field isn't marked `readonly`, which doesn't quite communicate that intent. Using actual fields and dropping the `Tuple` altogether, you can come up with a more standard `GetHashCode` implementation.

> *That way I should take advantage of the Tuple class and avoid its inconvenients.*

You're not getting anything out the `Tuple`. Get rid of it, it's only obfuscating the class' implementation.

---

Also, you're not instantiating your `Tuple` the idiomatic way. This:

> ```
> _impl = new Tuple<string, int, int, int>(unitID, address, comPort, id);
> ```

Should be written like this and leverage generic type parameter inference:

```
_impl = Tuple.Create(unitID, address, comPort, id);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So what should be the implementation of GetHashCode() ? I like the idea to use the Tuple implementation instead of making my own. I may also add or remove some fields in the future. So I won't have any work to do if I keep the tuple's GetHashCode() implementation.

Comment: @Vincent that's a question Jon Skeet has [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/263416/1188513) on Stack Overflow - as for the `Tuple`, you're basically abusing it to hold what should be private fields. This "key" class is no different from any other POCO class in your project.

Comment: +1 for noting that using the Tuple here is not contributing anything that a basic POCO couldn't handle.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Thanks for the link to the Jon Skeet's answer.

Answer (score 3):

First off, I'd venture to say that `Key` is probably too generic of a name, and doesn't give much information about the type. I'd suggest the following replacements that'd give more detail:

- `TupleKeyAlias`
- `FourTupleKeyAlias`

I'd go with the first one, unless you can come up with a better name on your own.

In addition, rather than creating your own specialized implementation, why couldn't you have just created a subclass of `Tuple<string, int, int, int>`, like this:

```
class TupleKeyAlias 
    : Tuple<string, int, int, int>
{ }
```

And then just used everything that's already implemented on the `Tuple` class without needing to create `override` methods.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually the class isn't named Key but something like MyClassKey. I changed the name for confidentiality concerns. By deviring the tuple class instead of wrapping it, I keep the ItemN properties. Shouldn't be better to get rid of them ? Moreover I don't need any getters or setters for this class.

Comment: @Vincent I think it's okay to keep the `itemN` properties, in case you ever have a need to access specific values from the tuple.